# Compiling *.py files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to compile python source files without success. According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/compileall.html), **compileall.compile_dir** function has "**ddir**" parameter, which (I guess) specifies the destination folder for .pyc files. I try to compile it with this script:

```
import compileall

compileall.compile_dir(".", force=1, ddir=".")
```

but it doesn't work. I see output from terminal (compiling, listing etc.) but pyc files are not generated. Anyone can help me understand where pyc files are stored and how to change that default behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check `__pycache__` directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `__pycache__` directories. Since Python 3.2, the compiled files are collected in `__pycache__` directories.

See [PEP 3147: PYC Repository Directories - What’s New In Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html?highlight=__pycache__#pep-3147-pyc-repository-directories).

BTW, `ddir` is not destination directory. According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html#compileall.compile_dir):

> If *ddir* is given, it is prepended to the path to each file being
>   compiled for use in compilation time tracebacks, and is also compiled
>   in to the byte-code file, where it will be used in tracebacks and
>   other messages in cases where the source file does not exist at the
>   time the byte-code file is executed.

Comment: Thanks falsetru. Could you tell me where is that folder located on linux? Thanks

Comment: @Davita, They're located the same directory where the package/module exist. Try `find . -name __pycache__`

Comment: Wow, I lost 2 hours searching while it was in front of my nose :D thanks :)